# Listing dataframes, matrices and so on in the application

Tags: shiny

I have used the below code to see the dataframes, matrices, functions and so on in my environment.
But is there a way to use this below code in server.R so that I can see what all dataframes, matrices are there in my application? I tried below code in my server.R but it not listing . Can anyone please help?

```
purrr::map_dfr(ls(envir=.GlobalEnv),~tibble(object_name = .,object_class=class(get(.))[[1]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Place it inside an `observe` call in your server. Save the result and then print it.

```r
  observe({shinyenv = purrr::map_dfr(ls(envir=.GlobalEnv),~tibble(object_name = .,object_class=class(get(.))[[1]])) 
  print(shinyenv)
})
```

This will print the objects in the environment to your console. Result from a test of one of my apps:

```r
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   object_name  object_class  
   <chr>        <chr>         
 1 activities   data.frame    
 2 arableLand   data.frame    
 3 challenges   data.table    
 4 crops        data.frame    
 5 diseases     data.table    
 6 pest_data    data.frame    
 7 rainfall     data.frame    
 8 server       function      
 9 ui           shiny.tag.list
10 weatherTable data.frame    
11 width        numeric
```

Comment: Great thanks . But I have a question. In my app. There is also renderTable, renderPrint etc... even this should be shown right? I mean even these are Functions. Is it not possible to show them??

Comment: functions like renderTable are not in your global environment, they are a different environment called the namespace.

Comment: Cool. Can I replace globalenv with namespace and try? Sorry I may be wrong. Can u please guide

Comment: replace your `````ls(envir=.GlobalEnv)```` with ````ls("package:shiny")````. However, this will display all the functions in the shiny package, even the ones you don't use in the app

Comment: Oh got it. But actually as u said, it ll show all functions. Can we not give my application name and try? If it slows all functions then I think it won’t be no iset anyways thanks for ur time

Comment: what exactly do you want to do and why?

Comment: For any shiny applications. I need what all inputs, outputs, functions, arguments of functions , data frames etc . Input in the sense, action button(along with input Id) and al. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just use the app.R script? It has what you are asking for

Comment: Like? What exactly you mean?

Comment: Your script, the file where you have the code for the application, shows the functions you use with arguments. I am not sure why you want to get what's already in the script

Comment: I understand. Say I have 5000 lines of code in application. In just a click I need to know all information. Like what funtions, inputs, outputs are there. Makes sense ?:)

Comment: Sorry. Wanted to check if you need anything else from me?

Comment: You want to do this in the shiny app? If so, you can simply add a page with all your embedded code. Although with 5000 lines that might be tedious. Alternative is to use buttons on specific ui elements and outputs that when pressed will display the code used to generate the ui and/or output

Comment: Yeah ur right. Is there a way to display of input and output in R shiny app?

Comment: Yes, ask another question as I can't answer it here.

Comment: Hi I have raised another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290759/is-there-a-way-to-list-the-objectsdataframes-functions-argsfuntions-inputs