# Is there a way to list the objects(dataframes, functions, args(funtions), inputs, outputs of a shiny app

Tags: shiny

Is there a way to list the objects(dataframes, functions, args(funtions), inputs, outputs of a shiny app. In the below app, there are inputs likes actionButton(), numericInput() etc, and outputs like renderText(). Is there a way to list these along with there ID'd (eg action Button has "goButton") and so on.

Also, there is a function declared here called "asd" with arguments (3,4). Can we also list these information ? please guide

ui.R

```
source("fun.R")

pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("actionButton test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("n", "N:", min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
    br(),
    actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
    p("Click the button to update the value displayed in the main panel.")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("nText")
  )
)
```

server.R

```
function(input, output) {

  # builds a reactive expression that only invalidates 
  # when the value of input$goButton becomes out of date 
  # (i.e., when the button is pressed)
  ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    input$n
  })

  output$nText <- renderText({
    asd(3,4)
  })
}
```

fun.R

```
asd <- function(a,b)
{ 
c <- a + b
return(c)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use action buttons, show, hide from shinyjs and verbatimtextoutput to have show code for specific output in your app. Like this:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

asd <- function(a,b)
{ 
  c <- a + b
  return(c)
}

ui <- pageWithSidebar(


  headerPanel("actionButton test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("n", "N:", min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
    br(),
    actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
    p("Click the button to update the value displayed in the main panel.")
  ),
  mainPanel(

    useShinyjs(),

    tags$head(tags$style("

    #nText {
      color: #333;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      border-radius: 4px;');

    }

    pre {
        font-size: 90%;
        color: #c7254e;
        border-radius: 4px;

    }")),

    verbatimTextOutput("nText"),
    actionButton("showtextcode", "Show Code"),
    verbatimTextOutput("textoutputcode"),
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # builds a reactive expression that only invalidates 
  # when the value of input$goButton becomes out of date 
  # (i.e., when the button is pressed)

  shinyjs::hide("textoutputcode")

  ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    input$n
  })

  output$nText <- renderText({
    asd(2,3)
  })

  output$textoutputcode <- renderText({
    "output$nText <- renderText({
        asd(2,3)
})"
  })

  observeEvent(input$showtextcode, {

    if(input$showtextcode %% 2) {
      shinyjs::show("textoutputcode")
    } else {
      shinyjs::hide("textoutputcode")
    }
  }) 


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Result:
[image]

If you want to show *all* of your code for the app, you *can* create a separate tab that shows the full code placing everything in verbatimTextOutput. However, just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*. For instance, if your shiny app spans 5000 lines then this is a bit silly!

It would be much better to simply include a github link to the source code of the app, if users are interested they can simply follow the link. Remember shiny is designed to share interactive output and not full source code.

Comment: Thanks for the time. But basically my question is little tricky . My thinking is, Say we have shiny application (any application for that matter). The file name is "ABC.R" (both ui.R and server.R) Fine? Now, Irrespective of any funtions, dataframes, matrices, inputs, outputs in the application. The user should know the details. In your code, you urself have written ````asd(2,3)```` as a object. But do you suggest me that I need to write this for all application(having 100 functions in it).

Comment: Contd... Basically my thought is I need to create a workflow in my application meaning, What all inputs are there (I mean the labels), What all outputs are there (Eg. output$table),                                                                       
What all dataframes are there? What all functions are there(There arguments as well) and so on. So if I have this ready. For any applications (even it is 2000 lines or 20 lines),

Comment: Contd .. I can understand in details its structure it self. Makes sense? Actually to be frank it is very hard to explain, many did not understand what I am trying to do. But this is something very useful I believe.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand what you want. Do you want to display the code? Or you want a button that retrieves the R code once you click on it, without you having to manually type it out like I have?

Comment: Can we get into chat box? I can explain in detail

Comment: I don't know how else you can explain this

Comment: I don't know how else you can explain this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211968/discussion-between-mr-rlover-and-imran-p).